# Vertical Tabs with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want tabs along the left side of the page instead of across the top.  I'm already loading jQuery for other reasons (effects), so I prefer using jQuery to another UI framework.  Searches on "vertical tabs jquery" yield links to works-in-progress.

Is getting Vertical Tabs to work across browsers fraught, or is it so trivial that, once you have a solution, it doesn't seem worthwhile to post example code?

Answer (score 49):

Have a look at [the jQuery UI vertical Tabs Docu](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical).
I try out it, it worked fine.

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Vertical Tabs
----------------------------------*/
.ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
</style> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs().addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
        $("#tabs li").removeClass('ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-left');

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try here:

http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/

A look at the Freedom tab might have what you need.

Let me know if you find something you like.  I worked on the exact same problem a few months ago and decided to implement myself.  I like what I did, but it might have been nice to use a standard library.

Comment: Nanotabs is really cool.  I will be looking for places to use it.

Answer (score 6):

I've created a vertical menu and tabs changing in the middle of the page. I changed two words on the code source and I set apart two different divs

menu:

```
<div class="arrowgreen">
  <ul class="tabNavigation"> 
    <li> <a href="#first" title="Home">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#secund" title="Home">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

content:

```
<div class="pages">
  <div id="first">
    CONTENT 1
  </div>
  <div id="secund">
    CONTENT 2
  </div>
</div>
```

the code works with the div apart

```
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.pages > div');

    $('div.arrowgreen ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

        $('div.arrowgreen ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Comment: looks like his click event is on the a tags

Answer (score 4):

```
//o_O\\  (Poker Face) i know its late
```

**just add beloww css style**

```
<style type="text/css">

   /* Vertical Tabs ----------------------------------*/
 .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
 .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
 .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
 .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
 .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; }
 .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}

</style>
```

UPDATED ! http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

Comment: The given link is dead. Do you have new link?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect vertical tabs to need different Javascript from horizontal tabs.  The only thing that would be different is the CSS for presenting the tabs and content on the page. JS for tabs generally does no more than show/hide/maybe load content.

Answer (score 1):

Another options is Matteo Bicocchi's jQuery mb.extruder tabs plug-in: 
http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-extruder/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/).  Tabs are semantically just a list of items styled in a particular way.  You don't even necessarily need javascript to make vertical tabs work as the various examples at Listamatic show.

Answer (score 0):

super simple function that will allow you to create your own tab / accordion structure here: http://jsfiddle.net/nabeezy/v36DF/

```
bindSets = function (tabClass, tabClassActive, contentClass, contentClassHidden) {
        //Dependent on jQuery
        //PARAMETERS
        //tabClass: 'the class name of the DOM elements that will be clicked',
        //tabClassActive: 'the class name that will be applied to the active tabClass element when clicked (must write your own css)',
        //contentClass: 'the class name of the DOM elements that will be modified when the corresponding tab is clicked',
        //contentClassHidden: 'the class name that will be applied to all contentClass elements except the active one (must write your own css)',
        //MUST call bindSets() after dom has rendered

        var tabs = $('.' + tabClass);
        var tabContent = $('.' + contentClass);
        if(tabs.length !== tabContent.length){console.log('JS bindSets: sets contain a different number of elements')};
        tabs.each(function (index) {
            this.matchedElement = tabContent[index];
            $(this).click(function () {
                tabs.each(function () {
                    this.classList.remove(tabClassActive);
                });
                tabContent.each(function () {
                    this.classList.add(contentClassHidden);
                });
                this.classList.add(tabClassActive);
                this.matchedElement.classList.remove(contentClassHidden);
            });
        })
        tabContent.each(function () {
            this.classList.add(contentClassHidden);
        });

        //tabs[0].click();
    }
bindSets('tabs','active','content','hidden');
```