# How to create a vertical tabs using the JQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I tried the vertical tabs in the demos,but that make my horizontal ones vertical,too,which is not what i want.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have two tabs on same screen? post some code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773074/vertical-tabs-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

From this [demo](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html), they already had difference CSS class. I don't think it should mess up with your horizontal tabs.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs().addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
    $("#tabs li").removeClass('ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-left');
 });
```

give it a try. (view source)

Comment: The demo does not make the text vertical - like a binder