# Vertical "tab" component on jQuery UI site

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery UI features a nice-looking "vertical tabbing" widget to switch between chapters [on its own website.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

[image]

Does anybody know whether this builds on some kind of standard widget (you *would* expect that UI's very own "tabs" component is being used for this, but no dice!), or whether it is something custom made? A cursory glance at the code makes me suspect the latter..... This would come in very handy in a project I'm working on.

Comment: Looking at demos.js, it seems to be custom stuff of just adding and removing the class `demo-config-on` onClick. The click event starts on line 66 of the demos.js file, which leads me to believe your conclusion that it is custom made, to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the UI Tabs Widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

You can Style your vertical tabs with css in an easy Way because you can define an unordered list, style it to your needs and add UI Tabs magic. Here is some really basic styling... http://jsfiddle.net/CR6Eg/

```
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item">
    <a href="#fragment-slide-1"><span>Volutpat ut wisi enim</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item">
    <a href="#fragment-slide-2"><span>Volutpat ut wisi enim</a>
</li>

<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="fragment-slide-1" style="">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="fragment-slide-2" style="">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah-ha! There is a "vertical tabs" subproject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773074/vertical-tabs-with-jquery). I will check that out, I may be able to work with that already. If you have any hints on where to get this specific style in a package, I'd be interested to see it nevertheless.

Comment: You really don't need the vertical tabs subproject. It's very easy to do... You need only some basic css and html knowledge.

Comment: @gears thanks! I got it working with the vertical tabs thingy, I need the tabs next to the content area. Anyway, this is the way to go.

Comment: @gears yup, that is essentially what the vertical tabs thing does as well (just stole the CSS from there). Yours is nicer though, I find myself approaching that as I work on it