# Converting horizontal tabs to vertical tabs

Tags: jquery, css

I have am trying to modify the following [example](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/tabs/) and make vertical tabs

I think I acheived this to some extent, and the only thing missing is aligning the tab contents with the top of the container. (The tab content is displayed below the tab list).

I am stuck as I do not know how to do this. Here is the modified code.

I apologize in advance for the many lines of code. I am new to web design, and even though this looks complicated to me, I am sure it is straightforward to the erst of you!

#### CSS

```
body {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 10px normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    }
.container {width: 500px; margin: 10px auto;}
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 20%;
    }
ul.tabs li {
    float: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}   
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 200%;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }
.tab_content {
    padding: 120px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    }
.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
    });

});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="container"> 
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <li><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab2">The Third</a></li> 
</ul> 
<div class="tab_container"> 
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"> 
        <h2>Gallery</h2> 
        <p>Text 1 </p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 
        <h2>Submit</h2> 
        <p>Text 2 </p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content"> 
        <h2>The last one</h2> 
        <p>Text 3 </p> 
    </div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/4BEm2/)

Comment: There's no such thing as `float: top`, and you've got about 200% more styles applied to things than you need. :)

Comment: haha, I agree with you. I will begin scrapping things out once I get the idea working (I think I am almost there thanks to Matt's suggestions). I am also new yo all of this and need some time to figure the basic stuff... For instance thanks for pointing out that there is no such thing as `float: top`!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this CSS rule:

```
.tab_content {
    padding: 120px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

to this:

```
.tab_content {
    padding-left: 120px;
    min-height: 240px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/4BEm2/1/

---

***Edit*** OP asks *"If you click on the third tab, you can notice that the bottom border disappears. Is there a way around that? (and ideally making the right border of the active tab disappearing)"*

Change this CSS rule:

```
html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

to this:

```
ul.tabs li.active {
    background: #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/4BEm2/2/

Comment: Thanks a mill!! One last thing: If you click on the third tab, you can notice that the bottom border disappears. Is there a way around that? (and ideally making the right border of the active tab disappearing)

Comment: @Matt: is this a good approach to develop a vertical tab in my website? (in other words do you suggest I use some other jquery library to achieve the desired tab effect?)

Comment: If it works, it works. At the very least you should put it into a plugin, though. If you do want to use someone else's already-working code, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773074/vertical-tabs-with-jquery)/[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855782/vertical-tab-component-on-jquery-ui-site).

Comment: @Matt Ball: Nice explanation. I have a question: why does removing the "#" from `#tab1` or `#tab2`... in the html code will result in the tab system not to function correctly?

Comment: @Rami: sorry, I don't understand your question - removing the `#` from where, exactly? The CSS or the JavaScript?

Comment: @Matt Ball: check: http://jsfiddle.net/aXbwk/3/ Notice how tab 1 and 2 are working, however tab 3 isn't. What I did was, in the html body, under the `<ul class="tabs"> ` I wrote: `<li><a href="tab3">The Third</a></li> ` instead of `<li><a href="#tab3">The Third</a></li> `. Removing the `#` causes the code to malfunction.

Comment: @Rami: that's because jQuery needs the `#` from the `href` attribute, to turn it into an ID selector. An alternative would be to remove the `#` from the href, and change `$(activeTab).fadeIn();` to `$('#'+activeTab).fadeIn();`. The nice thing about having the `#` in the href, though, is that it degrades gracefully when JavaScript is turned off.