# What is the CSS to get jQuery UI Tabs working, not to style

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I been trying to loose the style that the custom jqueryui.css uses for Tabs, but I can't find the piece of code that just get it working, and not style it. Anybody knows what exactly the css is, removing everything but the css to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery UI CSS theming are built up around the classes named ui-*. For example:

ui-widget
ui-widget-content
ui-corner-all

And for tabs you get: ui-tabs

Open up the .css to see what they do.

I don't think you can remove all the classes and just have the functionality, since most of them are needed for tabs to work.

If I were you and wanted to remove all the styling, I would edit the .css and make small changes and see what happens. For example, remove the default font, background-color etc. When you are pleased with the result I would keep the remaining classes as they are and build your application around them.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question once, and a user was kind enough to provide me with a  minimal example. See the comments on [Vertical "tab" component on jQuery UI site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855782/vertical-tab-component-on-jquery-ui-site) (JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CR6Eg/))