# jquery ui widget for tabbed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Jquery ui doesn't show examples of a tabbed content widget like the list on the right http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#default where you choose examples (default functionality, content via ajax, etc)

Does anyone know how to create a similar tabbed content using jquery UI? No addition scripts.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it the navigation menu on the right at jqueryui.com you are interested in duplicating? If so, I wouldn't refer to that as *tabbed content*. It just looks like a regular HTML/CSS navigation menu to me.

Comment: yes. I'm assuming that it was made with jquery ui, but there is no example of it. we just have the top tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773074/vertical-tabs-with-jquery) there is a link to [vertical jQuery UI tabs demo](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html).

Also [Wijmo](http://wijmo.com/) Open has added an alignment property to [their jQuery UI based tabs](http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/#tabs%7Calignment) if the no additional script constraint can be stretched.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you can use the jquery ui tabs script you linked to. Use CSS to get the tabs on the right hand side and vertical, instead of along the top and horizontal.

jQuery wise I see no difference. Its a styling thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a widget itself but a combination of event handlers and CSS. You can check the source code of it:

http://jqueryui.com/js/demos.js

I'd like to say also that the AJAX content loading is not a great solution as it is used in jQuery UI demos, because they load content via AJAX and they update hash part or URL, but you can't go back in browser history and you can't enter directly to a demo by using a special hash.