# how to make a div appear when another div is clicked

Tags: jquery

I hope you clever people can help me here.

So first, take a look at this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/BvCVu/17/

I would like it so that when button1 is clicked some text will appear in the white area, 
and then when button2 is clicked the old text disappears and som new comes up etc.

(I would also like if the text that appears when button1 is clicked is shown as default when the page loads. )

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, Eg. Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773074/vertical-tabs-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need some other div for the white area so that it all lays out properly like:

```
<div class="content-area" style="float:right"></div>
```

As far as the JavaScript is concerned it would then be something like this:

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
   $(".content-area").html("This is my text.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made minor modifications to the DOM for the following solutions:

```
<div class='overdiv'>
    <a href='#'><div class='button button1'>button 1<span class="data">b1</span></div></a>
    <a href='#'><div class='button button2'>button 2<span class="data">b2</span></div></a>
    <a href='#'><div class='button button3'>button 3<span class="data">b3</span></div></a>
    <a href='#'><div class='button button4'>button 4<span class="data">b4</span></div></a>
    <div class="whitespace"></div>
</div>
```

This will work as you want I believe. It will also work if you have multiple `.overdiv`'s if you do something like this or plan to in the future as everything is using classes.

```
$(".overdiv").find(".button").click( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.closest(".overdiv").children(".whitespace").text($this.text());
});
$('.button1').click();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/BvCVu/18/)

You could also do something like this if you want different text to show up (just change what is within the `.data` elements if you want something different to show up:

```
$(".overdiv").find(".button").click( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.closest(".overdiv").children(".whitespace").text($this.find(".data").text());
});
$('.button1').click();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/BvCVu/21/)