# Vertical jQuery Tabs with Text wrapped in tabs of longer than tab width

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

Using the following example ([Vertical Tabs (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773074/vertical-tabs-with-jquery) I was able to for the jquery tabs vertically.

**HTML**

```
<div id="ProductTabs" style="height:685px;overflow:scroll;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-0"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-1"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-2"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-3"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-4"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-6">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-5"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-7">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-6"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-8">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-7"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-9">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-8"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-10">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-9"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-11">Quick long description exceeding tab width<span title ="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin color-for-10"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <<div id="tabs-1">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-2">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-3">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-4">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-5">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-6">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-7">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-8">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-9">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-10">...</div>
    <<div id="tabs-11">...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-tabs-vertical {
    width: 65em;
    display: flex;
}

    .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
        padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
        float: left;
        width: 12em;
        overflow:hidden;

    }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
            clear: left;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
            border-right-width: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
        }

            .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
                clear:both;
                display:block;
            }

            .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
                padding-bottom: 0;
                padding-right: .1em;
                border-right-width: 1px;
            }

    .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
        padding: 1em;
        float: right;
        width: 51em;
    }
```

**Script**

```
    $(function () {
        $("#ProductTabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
        $("#ProductTabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
    });
```

I am having trouble to figure out how to wrap long text inside the individual tabs.  The only style that seems to work is overflow: hidden in CSS. Tried (but not limited to) display: flex, text-wrap: normal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Applied the following change (white-space:normal;) :

**CSS**

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
    white-space:normal;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-right-width: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
}
```

and

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    max-width: 12em;
    display: block;
}
```